# Is this possible to have hybrid deployment of Odoo POS

Tags: deployment, odoo-8, point-of-sale

I am planning to deploy Odoo Community POS for my electronics store. I want this installation to be done on on-premises and in the cloud. Like my store operators can use the software on both offline/ online modes depending on the availability of the internet connection. While doing operations offline, I want the data to be auto-synced on the availability of internet. In the start, I will be having a standard Odoo Community version installation but I might build some features and add custom models too.

Which deployment option will suit me more? http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html#setup-install-source

Is there any possibility to have an Odoo Community edition hybrid deployment (on-premises and cloud at the same time).

Is this possible to make database auto-sync for both on-premises and cloud databases?

Comment: Yes you can do this..

Comment: Can you please share a little more explanation. Which options I have to go with the installation SaaS, Packaged, or Source? If you have any reference link/ document please do share.

Comment: You want to install SaaS ? or just community version ? Sorry for late answer.

Comment: Just a community version. The could which I have is a private one. I want to have same applications deployed on both local and could and want to sync both. When there will be internet connectivity I want an application to go with cloud DB and when there no connectivity it can go with local DB and later it merge changes once the connectivity is back.

Comment: Refer this link: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html

Might it will be useful to you